# Dynamic edit and delete of the table contents of specific row

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <TITLE>Category selection</TITLE>

    <style>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    function getsubcat(val) {
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "get_subcat.php",
        data:'subcat_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#subcat-list").html(data);
        }
        });
    }

    function selectcat(val) {
    $("#search-box").val(val);

    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function arrangeSno()

        {
               var i=0;
                $('#pTable tr').each(function() {
                    $(this).find(".sNo").html(i);
                    i++;
                 });

        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".add-row").click(function(){
               // var cat = $("#cat_name").val();
                var sno = $('#pTable tr').length;
                var cat = $("#cat-list").val();

                var display = $("#displayname").val();
                var subcat = $('#subcat-list').val();
                var order = $('#privilage').val();
                var markup = "<tr><td>" + sno + "</td><td>"+ cat + "</td><td>" + display + "</td><td>"+ subcat+ "</td><td>"+ order+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit' value='Edit'></td></tr>";
                $("table tbody").append(markup);
            });

        });    
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </br></br>
    <form method="POST" action="">
    <div id="results">
    <h3 align="center">Welcome<i>&nbsp&nbsp<?php echo$row['email']?></i></h3>
    <h3 align="center"><strong>Choose Your Templates</strong></h3>
    </br></br>
    <div align="center">
    <div class="row">


    <label>Select your Category:</label>
    <select name="category" id="cat-list" class="demoInputBox"  onChange="getsubcat(this.value);">
    <option value="">Select Category</option></td>
    <?php
    $results=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM category");
    foreach($results as $category) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $category["cat_name"]; ?>"><?php echo $category["cat_name"]; ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </select>

    </div>
    </br>

    <div class="row">
    <label> Display Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="display_name" id="displayname"/>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <label> Select your Subcategory:</label>
    <select name="pagename" id="subcat-list" class="demoInputBox">
    <option value="select">Select</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div>
    <label>Set Order</label>
    <select name="privilage" id="privilage">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <div></br>
    <label>Database</label>
    <input type="text" id="db" name="database" value="<?php echo $row['databasenme'];?>" readonly />
    </div>

    <div></br>

    <input type="button" class="add-row" value="Submit">

        </form>
    </div>

    </form>
    </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>

    <table id="pTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Slno</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Display Name</th>
                    <th>Subcategory</th>
                    <th>Order</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Context:
This is the code for displaying and editing the form created. Firstly when clicking the submit button in the form , the form details will be added in the table row .I want to edit that row details dynamically and to enter that table contents to a database.

```
        <?php
        require('connection.php');
        session_start();
        $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `main_regis` WHERE `databasenme`= '". $_SESSION["databasenme"]."'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        ?>
        <html>
        <head>
        <TITLE>Category selection</TITLE>

        <style>
        body{width:610px;font-family:calibri;}
        .frmDronpDown {border: 1px solid #7ddaff;background-color:#C8EEFD;margin: 2px 0px;padding:40px;border-radius:4px;}
        .demoInputBox {padding: 10px;border: #bdbdbd 1px solid;border-radius: 4px;background-color: #FFF;width: 50%;}
        .row{padding-bottom:15px;}
           form{
                margin: 20px 0;
            }
            form input, button{
                padding: 5px;
            }
            table{
                width: 100%;
                margin-bottom: 20px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            table, th, td{
                border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
            }
            table th, table td{
                padding: 10px;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style>
        </head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
        function getsubcat(val) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "get_subcat.php",
            data:'subcat_id='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#subcat-list").html(data);
            }
            });
        }

        function selectcat(val) {
        $("#search-box").val(val);

        }
        </script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function arrangeSno()

            {
                   var i=0;
                    $('#pTable tr').each(function() {
                        $(this).find(".sNo").html(i);
                        i++;
                     });

            }
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".add-row").click(function(){
                   // var cat = $("#cat_name").val();
                    var sno = $('#pTable tr').length;
                    var cat = $("#cat-list").val();

                    var display = $("#displayname").val();
                    var subcat = $('#subcat-list').val();
                    var order = $('#privilage').val();
                    var markup = "<tr><td>" + sno + "</td><td>"+ cat + "</td><td>" + display + "</td><td>"+ subcat+ "</td><td>"+ order+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit' value='Edit'></td></tr>";
                    $("table tbody").append(markup);
                });

            });    
        </script>

        </head>



        <body>
<form method="POST" action="">
       <label>category</label>
<input type="text" name="category" id="category" />
 <label>sub category</label>
<input type="text" name="sub_category" id="sub_category" />
 <label>Display name</label>
<input type="text" name="display" id="display" />
 <label>privilege</label>
<input type="text" name="privilege" id="privilege" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="add-row"/>
</form>
        <table id="pTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>Slno</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Display Name</th>
                        <th>Subcategory</th>
                        <th>Order</th>
                        <th>Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Context: I have a form that contains category and subcategory. After selecting the category and the corresponding subcategory i need to enter the values dynamically into a table displayed on the bottom of the form without entering the data into the database.The working code for this is displayed here. I wanted to edit each row dynamically by clicking the edit button and then save the content into the table.

The code contain java script portion to include each row dynamically but it does not contain any id value to be passed to the data. So i cannot edit the row dynamically by clicking the edit button.

The form contain category field, sub category field, display name, privilege and these values are inserted into the table by clicking add row button. Dynamically an edit button appears inside the table but on clicking the edit button i cannot edit the row dynamically.

Comment: `include each row dynamically but it does not contain any id value to be passed to the data. So i cannot edit the row dynamically by clicking the edit button` You can either bind the events as you iterate through the rows using positional selectors starting from the current rows processed or add a custom attribute such as `data-action-edit` to the button and then bind to it using that as a selector. Either way you need to bind the events after the DOM has been written or use delegate event binding if you bind before the DOM is written.

Comment: You should really narrow down your code and only include the minimal amount possible while still being explanatory and verifiable.

Comment: Why are you including two versions of jQuery on each page?